# Removing the "RECENT" sidebar entry of Nautilus (16.04 LTS)

Tags: 16.04, unity, nautilus

I wish to remove the "RECENT" entry from the sidebar of Nautilus.

Reviewing similar previous questions, answers always seem to refer to either *adding* it, or to removing the recent *log* but not to the sidebar entry.

Removing the entry is hopefully possible, right? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[In Security and Privacy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXjZI.png)
Disabling the "record" option (settings->security and privacy->files and apps) also disables the Nautilus sidebar entry.
It was simple after all.